# ReactJS How to change an icon (SVG) onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI's Accordion. I replaced the default arrow button with my own SVG. I have two SVGs, one upper arrow (^) when the modal is collapsed and one down arrow (∨) when it is open. When the ^ is clicked I would like to change it to ∨. How can I achieve this?

```
 <Accordion.Title active={this.state.activeIndex === idx} index={idx} onClick={this.clic}>
 <div className="fleche">
      <FlecheBasSVG // Down arrow
      onClick={<FlecheBasSVG />}/> {/* Up arrow */}
      Version {idx + 1} - {elem.etat ? t(`flot.split.etat.${elem.etat}`) : "flot.split.etat.INCONNU"}
</div>
</Accordion.Title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React handles things in a little bit different way than what you're trying to do. If you want to show and hide elements you can do this with a state variable. I have given an example below.

```
 state = {
     arrow: true;
 }

 const handleClick = () => {
     this.setState({arrow: !this.state.arrow})
 }


 <Accordion.Title active={this.state.activeIndex === idx} index={idx} onClick={this.clic}>
 <div className="fleche">
    // assuming the svg component has something to link an image (I am using an SRC prop, that probably wont work but is an example)
      {this.state.arrow ? <FlecheBasSVG onClick={this.handleClick} src="/path/to/up/image"/> : <FlecheBasSVG onClick={<this.handleClick} src="/path/to/up/image"/>}
      Version {idx + 1} - {elem.etat ? t(`flot.split.etat.${elem.etat}`) : "flot.split.etat.INCONNU"}
</div>
</Accordion.Title>
```